# NetLogo rnd:weighted-n-of by turtle variable

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a generator that uses the (corrected) Barabasi-Albert algorithm for a preferential attachment network in NetLogo. There are two parameters: number of (eventual) nodes, and number of edges added per node. The network extension has a version, but it is restricted to the case with 1 edge added per node.

Simplified complete model:

```
extensions [rnd]

to makeNW-BA
  clear-all
  let new-edges 4
  let popn 25
  create-turtles new-edges [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  ask turtles [ create-links-with other turtles with [not link-neighbor? myself] ]
  repeat popn - count turtles
  [ let targets rnd:weighted-n-of new-edges turtles [ count my-links ]
    create-turtles 1
    [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      create-links-with targets
    ]
  ]
end
```

The line `let targets rnd:weighted-n-of degree turtles [ count my-links ]` is creating a java error `(ClassCastException) while observer running _asm_proceduremakenwba_setprocedurevariable_11`. This is the first time I have used the `rnd` extension so I don't know if the problem is my coding, or there's actually a bug causing the java error.

**UPDATE**

I have now set up a turtles-own variable for degree (ie count my-links) and trying to do `let targets rnd:weighted-n-of new-edges turtles [ degree ]`. This gets me a NetLogo error instead, that `the observer can't access a turtle variable without specifying which turtle`. However, trying to add `of self` doesn't help.

Comment: not as an answer but as a speculation. It kinda has to be a bug. I question is, 'is it one in netlogo, Java or the extension?'

Comment: It is not probably not Java as it give me the same error. @Nicolas-Payette wrote it maybe he is familar.

Comment: Since it's causing a java error rather than a netlogo error, I have reported it as a possible bug in the rnd extension. But it could also be the way I have constructed the code, for example if it is self-referring in some way.

Comment: @King-Ink has the right solution, but the fact that it gives a Java exception is indeed a bug in the Rnd extension. See https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/issues/6#issuecomment-171982634.

Comment: Oh, and for the absence of a full-featured Barabási–Albert generator in the NW extension, see https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this produce the desired network?

```
let targets rnd:weighted-n-of new-edges turtles [ [count my-links] of ? ]
```

It is hard for me to eyeball it with new-eges set to 4. When I set it to 1 it seems to make a preferential attachment network.
It appears that (and let the voice of God disagree with me) [rnd:weighted-n-of] was designed to work with lists and has a hidden foreach or map in it resulting it an error in casting when given an agent set.

Comment: nicely done. I had tried `[count my-links] of ?` but that also produced an error. This breaks the parallel syntax with `n-of`, so is presumably a bug, but it does make it work.

Comment: At least a documentation issue.

Comment: `rnd` extension primitives were designed to work with _both_ lists and agentsets, but it uses "list" syntax (i.e., reporter tasks with `?`) for both. I would have liked it to be otherwise, but it's not easily done. See https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/issues/5 for discussion.

Comment: Proposal for fixing the syntax: https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension/pull/8. Opinions welcome!